# How to avoid same event trigger from two pods

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes-pod

I am creating a Java spring boot service, I am caching a few records from DB. I am matching current time with records time(a DB column) on every 2 minutes. If matched, I am sending email  with @Scheduled(cron = expression).
I am running this service on two pods. Hence for a single record event is triggering on both pods and sending same email.

In short I want to trigger email at a some scheduled time and I have two pods. Both pods are triggering email at same scheduled time

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your question is formulated too broad, it will be hard to formulate an answer. Providing a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help!

Comment: how exactly do you fetch your records?

Comment: I fetch records from database

Comment: I mean, do use plain JDBC, standard JPA or Spring Data? Can you share a small snippet how you retrieve the records? Most likely you'll need to use database locks and a additional column to set processing status to prevent double processing.

Comment: I am using JPA but I am caching the records(whose datetime field is of within 5 hrs) at service side, taking the records from cache and picking up for the matched time with current time.

Comment: how do you cache them? and, independent of that, can you add a field to support marking an entry as processed?

Comment: I am maintaining a TreeSet of records. I can add processed field in collection but how other pod will get to know. I am maintaining processed field in DB after it picked up and sent the email, but between that only other pod is also picking this up. As it is scheduled for the same time.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to allow the process to be triggered from outside of the application, e.g. using a RestController.
Then, you could move the scheduler outside of your application as well and trigger the endpoint using the URL of the Service. The request will be processed by one of the pods only.
In Kubernetes, you could use a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to get the singleton pattern modifying the application so as to have the single record processed once. You can use a locking mechanism so as to prevent double processing. The other solution is to use a StatefulSets controller on kubernetes, but that way you have only one pod working at a time.

Comment: Your statement about StatefulSets is not true, they still spawn multiple pods when scaled above 1, same as Deployments.

Comment: A singleton also does not help -- that only addresses parallel processing in *one* JVM on one pod.

Comment: Criztovyl, please read kubernetes docs about StatefuleSets : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/ . As you can read "provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods". As for the solution I agree that this is not the best solution for reliability and other reasons. As stated the best solution is to modify the application so as to get a lock on the single record. The same thing you suggested on your comments.

Comment: I am intrigued how we're misunderstanding each other. What I mean is that it is not relevant to OPs problem whether you use a normal Deployment or a StatefulSet to run two pods -- the code will still be running concurrently at those two pods. StatefulSets "only" guarantee ordering at startup and unique names of the pods.

Comment: You should read answers better before posting comments please.